# Cannot install enzyme-adapter-react-16

Tags: npm, enzyme

If I try to install **enzyme-adapter-react-16** in my project, I get this error :

```
PS C:\dev\test3\my-app> npm i enzyme-adapter-react-16
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"16.14.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.0.0-0" from enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.15.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\o_wat\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

I am unsure what this error message is trying to tell me. What is this error trying to tell me?

Answer (score 0):

Enzyme is dead it doesn't support react js 18
so u need to find a replacement. RTL is by no means an Enzyme drop-in replacement

take a look at [Enzyme is dead. Now what?](https://dev.to/wojtekmaj/enzyme-is-dead-now-what-ekl)